# Using Jira API (Not SOAP/REST Only) in a .NET application

Tags: jira

I am using Jira client for .NET via webservices; that enabled me to perform various tasks like  retrieve and update issues, fields etc.
The problem is when the issue is retrieved, some of the issue fields are in a wiki text format, e.g.

```
* Heading
*# point 1
*# point 2
```

I need to convert this format to plain text or HTML.
After doing some research I found that this functionality is provided in JIRA Api by

Class AtlassianWikiRenderer
http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/renderer/wiki/AtlassianWikiRenderer.html

My question is how can I use the functionality (AtlassianWikiRenderer) or other as specified in here http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/overview-summary.html
in a .NET project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use JIRA API classes from .NET app unless you provide an additional method of communication between your app and JIRA. This may be:

- extending JIRA SOAP service
- implementing your own REST service as a plugin

The other way is to get an issue view page as HTML and parse it. It's not that good but it works. Even some commercial products use this way.